# How to retrive select value of dynamic dropdown inside placeholder controls in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get a selected value of Dynamic Control which is inside placeholder

The below code is how i have created dynamic dropdown controls

```
string strQuery = "select distinct(TXT_BRANCH_NAME) from TBL_BRANCH_MASTER;";

DataTable dt_data = new DataTable();

dt_data = objdBConnection.getDataTableQuery(strQuery);

DropDownList ddlBranchList = new DropDownList();

if (dt_data.Rows.Count > 0)
{

int rowCount = dt_data.Rows.Count;

string[] assetList = new string[rowCount];

ddlBranchList.ID = "ddlBranchList";

ddlBranchList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select", ""));

ddlBranchList.CssClass = "form-control form-control-line";

for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
{

ddlBranchList.Items.Add(new ListItem(dt_data.Rows[j]["TXT_BRANCH_NAME"].ToString(), dt_data.Rows[j]
["TXT_BRANCH_NAME"].ToString()));
}
ddlBranchList.DataBind();
}
```

What I have tried:

Here Below i m fetching selected value of dropdown

```
string ddlBranch = "";

DropDownList ddlist = ((DropDownList)plcBranchddl.FindControl("ddlBranchList"));

ddlBranch = ddlist.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

but at last i m getting a null in ddllist dropdown references

Comment: where plcBranchddl is defined or what it is ?

Comment: plcBranchddl  is placeholder. where i m adding dynamic dropdown control.

Comment: Where is the code that you are using to attach the dynamic drop down to your dom?

Comment: If you add your dynamic controls in `PreInit` event than it might maintain its state and work normally. otherwise you will have to manually manage the state of the controls.

Comment: How to add dynamic control in PreInit event will you pls help me i m new in .net